# using uDMX API in c#

Tags: c#, api, dll, dllimport

I am relative new in c# and I want to use [this uDMX API](https://www.illutzmination.de/udmx-api.html?&L=1), but when I try to add the uDMX.dll file I get this error: "The reference is not vaild or not supported" (see screenshot (in german))
[- I can't add images yet -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJRsv.png)

Or am I doing it completely wrong? 
I did not find another uDMX api or .dll file.

Hope for your help and Ideas.

Comment: DllImport defaults to c language interface.  The dll uses standard windows interface.  Set the calling convention.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant import an unmanaged win32 dll into a managed c# application like that, you need to specify the methods and parameters yourself.

The uDMX api exposes these methods

```
bool _stdcall     Configure() ;
bool _stdcall     Connected() ;
bool _stdcall     ChannelSet(long Channel, long Value) ;
bool _stdcall     ChannelsSet(long ChannelCnt, long Channel, long* Value) ;
bool _stdcall     Info() ;
```

In order to use them in managed code, you need to provide the declaration, return value and parameters to .Net

This is done by marking a method as external and informing .Net where to find it, use the `DllImport` attribute found in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class uDMXTest
{
  [DllImport("uDMX.dll")]
  public static extern bool Configure();

  public static void Main()
  {
    bool result;
    result = Configure();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

Example on howto provide a declaration of the Configure method, and howto use it.
You can declare the other methods in uDMX.dll the same way - note you may need to give the full path to uDMX.dll in the DllImport attribute

More info here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks! What happens to the path if I build the project? Does it work then?

Comment: Most likely not, the uDMX.dll must be in same path as the executable . You can include the uDMX.dll in the project, and in the properties window for the dll set the "Copy to output directory" to Copy always.